# custom gradle plugin circular dependency

Tags: gradle, task

I have a custom gradle plugin and a Task named 'taskA', and I want to achieve this task sequence: [assemble] -> taskA -> [assemble].

code:

```
taskA.dependsOn variant.assemble
taskA.finalizedBy variant.assemble
```

Does gradle support to achieve this task sequence? If support, how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Gradle build, **every task** can be executed **only once**.

So **no**, your task sequence is **not possible**.